# Silencing false positives in Coverity Prevent

Tags: c++, coverity-prevent

I am using [Coverity Prevent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coverity#Products) on a C++ project. Is there some way of flagging false positives directly in the source code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coverity Static Analysis supports source code annotations.  They are described in the manual - since I don't know what version you're using I can't tell you exactly what section but it's in the book called "Checker Reference" in a section on "Models and Annotations."